# Handling Exception Gracefully

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a function which makes a http request and parses the response json data. The function is called in AsyncTask class. I have a function defined to check if there is connectivity before asynctask is invoked. But once the connection checker function returns true...my function runs within the asynctask class and the device loses connectivity the application force closes.

```
private void parseJson()
{
    // HTTP request and JSON parsing done here
}

class getData extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>
{


@Override
protected Void onPreExecute(Void...arg0)
{
    super.onPreExecute();
    //progress dialog invoked here
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void...arg0)
{
    parseJSON();
    return null;
}
@Override
protected Void onPostExecute(Void...arg0)
{
    super.onPostExecute();
    //UI manipulated here
}

}
```

how do i notify the user about the exception occuring in the doInBackground() method and handle exception properly since doInBackground() doesn't allow things like firing a toast message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do this Way**

```
class getData extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Boolaen>
{


@Override
protected Void onPreExecute(Void...arg0)
{
    super.onPreExecute();
    //progress dialog invoked here
}

@Override
protected Boolaen doInBackground(Void...arg0)
{
    try{ 
          parseJSON();
          return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackStrace();
    }

    return false;
}
@Override
protected Void onPostExecute(Boolaen result)
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result){
      //success
    }else{
      // Failure
    } 

    //UI manipulated here
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

My approach looked like this. Introducing a generic AsyncTaskResult, where you can either store your real return value (if you need one) or the exception which occured in `doInBackground()`. In `onPostExecute` you can check if an exception has occured and notify your user (or process your return value).

**AsyncTaskResult:**

```
public class AsyncTaskResult<T> {
    private T mResult;
    private Exception mException = null;

    public AsyncTaskResult() {
    }

    public AsyncTaskResult(T pResult) {
        this.mResult = pResult;
    }

    public AsyncTaskResult(Exception pException) {
        this.mException = pException;
    }

    public T getResult() {
        return mResult;
    }

    public boolean exceptionOccured() {
        return mException != null;
    }

    public Exception getException() {
        return mException;
    }
}
```

---

**AsyncTask:**

```
public class RessourceLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, AsyncTaskResult<String>> {

    public RessourceLoaderTask() {
    }

    @Override
    protected AsyncTaskResult<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            // Checked Exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new AsyncTaskResult<String>(e);
        }
        return new AsyncTaskResult<String>();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AsyncTaskResult<String> pResult) {
        if (!pResult.exceptionOccured()) {
            //...
        } else {
            // Notify user
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a field in `getData` class. Set it in `doBackground`, check it in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: i am a bit confused here...if an exception is caught anywhere inside the doInBackground() method doesn't the whole AsyncTask class freeze...does it reach the onPostExecute method?

Comment: @NirajAdhikari Check the other answers, they has the code that I just very briefly described.

Comment: This approach is ok for simple purposes, but what if you want to return a real value instead of that "success bool" from doInBackground?